# web api query with $filter return HRESULT : 0x80131904

Tags: 2013, rest, filter

I try to filter items using SP2013 web api such this request : `_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Activity')/items?$filter=Mylookupfield eq 'SomeValue'.`
All works fine in my DEV machine but in the customer PROD environment i get this issue.

> /span>m:code>-2146232060, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException
>   /span>m:message xml:lang="fr-FR">Exception de HRESULT :
>   0x80131904

Any help ?

Comment: I've seen this exception when the Content DB is full. Can you add items normally? If so I'd advise looking in the ULS logs for more details.

Comment: Is the field multi lookup on the other environment? Shouldn't your query use something like `MyLookupField/Title eq 'something'`?

Comment: Thank you for your response but i try both solution but any trace of solution so i try to see more nearly the issue and i get this when debugin :
http://win-f898lhd0rn9:7014/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Activites')/items?$filter=IPS_Prospect%20eq%201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can resolve the issue , the prod environment is an "fr" site collection so the query should be ($filtre=) at the  place of ($filter=) just write filter with fr language.